# How to add upper padding to a group of linked images

Tags: html, css

I have the following code for my website and I am trying to add padding to the group of image links on my the webpage

```
<ul class="">
        <a href="https://www.github.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/github.png" border="0" alt="Code" class="">
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.linkedin.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/linkedin.png" border="0" alt="Connect" class="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.twitter.com">
          <img style="height:auto; width:auto; max-width:50px; max-height:50px;" src="images/twitter.png" border="0" alt="Twitter">
        </a>
      </ul>
```

I also have the following CSS:

```
a{
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 400px;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
}
```

What would I need to do add vertical padding on the group image links for my website?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want, but try to use `padding-top`:

```
ul a img {
    padding-top: 10px;  /* Change the value according to your needs */  
}
```

Btw, You should give class to your element to target it more specifically.